# NativeScript: use custom objective-c imported class into Xcode project in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

basically I have some Objective-c class already existing and I want to use them in my NativeScript projet. Currently I have added those files to the Xcode project target and I want to be able to call my objective-c code from nativeScript js. I've read the doc but I don't understand it. It seems so complicated. basically currently all I want to do is be able to present my custom view controller by calling probably something along

```
const vc = MyCustomViewController.alloc.initWithNibName("xib file")
page.frame.ios.controller.present(vc,true, nil)
```

Am I obligated to create a plugin for that? Am I obligated to use my objective-c class to build a framework in Xcode and then import the framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out.

Actually what you need to do is first to compile your native iOS code into a framework. As per the documentation all your classes must inherit NSObject and all your function must be marked with @objc to be exposed to the objective-c Nativescript side if you write in swift. You will notice as well that **in a framework your bundle is not the main bundle**. In this example you can see how you can retrieve the bundle from the framework and load a xib from it.

[image]

Then you need to add your framework file to a Nativescript plugin. For that, you want to add the framework to the plugin's iOS folder `yourPlugin/platform/iOS/yourFramework.framework`.

then, you need to add your plugin to your app. You can add your local plugin by using the next command line. Notice the path end with the /src folder.

```
tns plugin add /path/to/yourplugin/src
```

Now, you can then call your native functions and classes without even importing them. Of course this works only on iOS. If you run your app on android, calling those methods will crash.

To show this viewController on your Nativescript side you will need to call the following code. By the way You can find documentation elsewhere to get a reference to the current `page` or `frame` object.

```
const controller = page.frame.ios.controller
const  vc = IOMediaViewController.create()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen
controller.presentViewControllerAnimatedCompletion(vc,true,null)
```